# What's the difference between "noun to verb" and "noun that verb" in meaning?

Tags: difference

Is there a subtle difference between those sentences in meaning?

> 1. A hero is a brave person who does things ***to*** help others.
> 2. A hero is a brave person who does things ***that*** help others.

Comment: The first implies intent or purpose.  The second indicates result.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so you may take my words with a grain of salt. "To help others" is normally understood as a purpose adjunct: it tells you why they help others. The that-clause in the second sentence is a relative clause modifying "things": what helps others is what a brave person does.

Comment: The difference is that the infinitival clause is a purpose adjunct, cf. "... who does things in order to help others", while the that clause is a relative one modifying "things", where we understand that he does things; things help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a very subtle difference in meaning.  In the first sentence, the emphasis is on helping others:

> A hero is a brave person who does things **to help others**.

In the second sentence, the emphasis is on the actions (things) that are done by the hero:

> A hero is a brave person **who does things** that help others.

You'd more likely use the first example for a hero who seeks out people who are in trouble and then does things to help them - imagine a hero who rescues people from captivity.  The emphasis is on the people.

The second example would be for a hero who does things that are good, with the goal that some possibly unknown people might benefit from those actions - imagine a hero who kills an evil witch.  The emphasis is on the heroic action.